# Application invoked by batch file goes in background window

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to install .net framework by using batch file

```
START /B /WAIT "" "dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe"
```

The problem here is that some users are facing the issue that dot net installer goes background (in some cases, not always) and user waits for something to happen. I really can't reproduce this scenario. Is there any way to explicitly force app to be in foreground.

Comment: Is there a reason you need the user to interact with the .NET installer? You could install it silently, no user interaction necessary.

Comment: Yes, actually :/.
There is a way we do silent invocation but in this case user needs to see it.

Comment: The user must have clicked on the screen.  Tell them to cut the mouse cord before it runs. ;)  You might like to add the `/max` switch to the start command.  Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native batch command or method that will keep your window in focus.

You will need a third-party utility or use something like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to write a script to keep your window in front.